# Why does data imported from AutoCAD appear different in ArcMap 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, import, autocad

I am importing information from AutoCAD into Arcmap 10.1.  I found after some issues that I need to give the incoming information geographic location, which works fine.  The problem is that all the data appears the same.  I have two maps with different points of collections, but when I bring over both maps, they give me the same data.

Pic1: is the data that I am pulling over from AutoCad

[image]
Pic2: is what appears in Arcmap 10.1.

[image]

If you look at the bottom, you will notice that they are both suppose to be the same, but they are not.  The title is different, and also when I bring it over to ArcMap 10.1, it has alot more points of data in the different areas.
I have bringing over alot of different maps, is it possible that my maps are reading data from a different map that I brought over before I was looking at these?

Comment: Try closing arcmap. Start windows task manager>processes. Then kill the arcgis cache manager process. I don't see the thread now but it is possible to delete the arcgis cache proxy objects.

Comment: Watch for hidden layers in CAD, Arcmap uses all layers whether they're hidden or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a question of symbology. Look in your attribute table and you should see that  the visible points have different values than the invisible points. You can then go in the layer properties > definition query in order to display only your points of interest or to layer properties > symbology to use different symbols.

On the other hand, you could read your CAD data, without importing it, just using drag and drop from ArcCatalog for the full CAD dataset (it will be read only, but you keep the symbology). See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_working_with_CAD_data/00100000002r000000/ for more details

Comment: While your answer did not help me, as there may be another issue.  It did give me an area to look which started me in the right direction.  As I said I still have an issue, which I will post in another question.